# know when access was granted to RD

Tags: active-directory, windows-server

I wasn't able to remote desktop to a windows server last week.

Now the admin said I already have access in the past.

And indeed, I am able to access it now… This delay caused issues; I want to be able to retrieve exactly at what time the access was granted to me… or maybe if I could find a failed login/auth from last week, that way I can also prove it.

Is there any log that I can get this information from?

Comment: If you have access, you can try the RDP activity logs on the server or you could view a permission change audit. Your RDP client might also have logs. It's hard to say without knowing what version of windows server you were trying to access or what RDP client you are using.

Comment: This question might be a better fit for https://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can use any SIEM tool which supports active directory management. I personally prefer ADAudit Plus. You can see demo in [link](http://demo.adauditplus.com/)